# make windows float behind xfce panel

Tags: 12.04, xubuntu, xfce-panel

I would like to make it so windows maximize behind the xfce panel.

basically so that all windows DO NOT treat the xfce panel as a dock.

I noticed that if I move the XFCE panel away from the screen edge, then windows will properly ignore it but .... I want the panel to touch the edge and have the windows all go behind it..

TIA

Comment: If the windows go behind the panel, it'll be impossible to minimize or drag n drop them, right? Because the title bar of the windows will be behind the panel. Is that convenient?

Comment: yes , very convenient if you saw my setup. I actually found the answer and will post it soon. I put all the info applets on the top panel and set it to expand as needed so that when a window is maximized i always see the clock above the title bar as well as network info etc... it looks really slick and I get more screen realestate. the panel at the bottom I use as a task manager and that ofcourse I don't want windows going under.

Comment: setting the panel to expand as needed leaves the right or left side open so you can minimize or close windows. If you set the panel as 100% transparent it actually looks really cool.

Comment: Here it is: http://www.webupd8.org/2011/05/get-minimalistic-wingpanel-like-xfce4.html And see also: http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=57&t=111926 @Joshua, thanks for sharing!

Comment: And latest xfce does have an option 'Don't reserve space on borders' ([see docs](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-panel/preferences)) that does exactly this thing out of the box.